# Can I have a regex validate the full string?

Tags: regex

I'm quite new to Regex'es, so I was wondering if this is possible?

Take a string and check that all characters are A-Z or a-z.

My best guess so far is:

```
"^[A-Za-z]*$"
```

But it seems to have some trouble if a character in the middle of the string is not a valid character (fx. "aaa__aa"). The `Regex.IsMatch` returns true.. :(

[EDIT]
A few comments on your answer rather than only a regex would be great :)

Comment: So that means it works. The '_' doesn't belong to the set you are checking ;^)

Comment: Didnt clarify myself too good.. Ill update the question

Comment: The regular expression `^[A-Za-z]*$` is almost certainly wrong. It allows for _no_ letters at all, since it would match an empty line (the `*` is for _zero_ or more). See some of the answers below for the use of `+` instead.

Comment: @Meeh: your request is unclear. You say that you want to check if the string contains _only_ A-Z or a-z, but then you are upset to discover that "aaa_aaa" is rejected. Do you see the conflict?

Comment: I'm sorry I were so unclear when asking this question. I got my answer though, so thanks all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are currely saying is
The string is only valid if it contains the characters between 0 - 9 or nothing

To check if the characters are a-z or A-Z you need to used

```
^[A-Za-z]*$
```

Which says
The string is only valid if the characters are between a - z or A - Z (inclusive) or nothing

**EDIT**
The new regex you have edited the previous one to works fine, and doesn't match anything with a underscore in. You may have an issue in your code implementation.

Comment: Unless this variety of regular expressions is different from what I'm familiar with, this actually says "The string is only valid if the characters are between a-z or A-Z _or it's a blank line_." The star means _zero_ or more times. A blank line would satisfy the zero requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
"^[A-Za-z]*$"
```

Comment: This will match the empty string since `^[A-Za-z]*$` says match any of A-Z or a-z _zero_ or more times. Zero allows for an empty line. @Meeh: Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want

```
"^[A-Za-z]+$"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should work.  You alternatively like to use something like:

```
^[A-Za-z]+$
```

to ensure that there is at least one alphabetic character.  What language are you using?  In python, this would be better achieved with the `isalpha()` function.  There may be similar functions in your chosen language.  Also, in a lot of implementations of regular expressions, you can simply do:

```
^\a+$
```

In some regular expression implementations (POSIX in particular), the `+` needs to be `\+`.

Answer (score 1):

`^[a-zA-Z]+$` should do the job. But when you want to catch sentence with spaces, 
`^[a-zA-Z\s]+$` will be better, where \s means space for this one. Or you may even extending it to catch punctuations character also.

Answer (score 0):

"aaa_aaa" is still a match because it matches the first block of a's.
By incorporating the '^' and'$' into your expression, you are indicating that the start of linemust first match, followed by a block of letters, followed by the end of line. This essentially means the whole string must match the expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main() {
    if (Regex.IsMatch("aaa_aa", "^[a-zA-Z]*$"))
      Console.WriteLine("Pigs can fly");
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to demonstrate that the earliest answer WFM.

Comment: Doesn't this still have the problem that it matches an empty line?

Comment: all characters in the empty string are alphabetical.  There was no requirement that empty strings shouldn't be permitted.

Comment: @p00ya: The OP is trying to validate a string, and he said "Take a string and check that all characters are A-Z or a-z." You may be right, but I seriously doubt that he wants to pass on a blank line.